# Input event exception after inflating layout in custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a CustomView that extends NestedScrollView and implements BottomSheetBehavior. I want to allow users of the custom view to pass in an XML attribute pointing to a layout to inflate inside of the NestedScrollView (which is the bottomsheet).

Upon study of the View lifecycle, I understand that I need to inflate the passed in layout after the view is on screen, so I am overriding the dispatchDraw (I've tried onDraw with equal success) like so:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    initPassedLayout();
}
```

It actually shows on the screen fine, however as soon as I touch the screen, I am getting this exception (none of which points to any of my code):

```
2019-04-08 16:15:12.001 15810-15810/com.demo E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
2019-04-08 16:15:12.002 15810-15810/com.demo E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-04-08 16:15:12.011 15810-15810/com.demo E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:293)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.resetTouchBehaviors(CoordinatorLayout.java:394)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:509)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2573)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.mai
2019-04-08 16:15:12.011 15810-15810/com.demo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-04-08 16:15:12.021 15810-15810/com.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo, PID: 15810
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior.onInterceptTouchEvent(BottomSheetBehavior.java:293)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.resetTouchBehaviors(CoordinatorLayout.java:394)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout.java:509)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2573)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3030)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3400)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:398)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12752)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5106)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4909)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7092)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7022)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7195)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
2019-04-08 16:15:12.021 15810-15810/com.demo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I understand that I need to inflate the passed in layout after the view is on screen" – Nah, you can inflate that immediately in the constructor.

Comment: Ok. If I do that it shows the bottom sheet only and not the underlying view. I'm setting the BottomSheetBehavior programmatically, which requires layoutparams like this:
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            BottomSheetBehavior behavior = new BottomSheetBehavior();
            layoutParams.setBehavior(behavior);

This can only be done once the view is showing, is that right? Calling from constructor, I get an NPE on layoutParams.

Comment: Yeah, a `View` will not yet have `LayoutParams` in its constructor. I will say that a `View` modifying its own `LayoutParams` is kinda abnormal, but if you really, really want to, they should be available in `onAttachedToWindow()`.

Comment: The problem was that initPassedLayout() was getting called too many times. Upon logging a few things, I saw dispatchDraw() is called over and over. A boolean 'hasInit' fixed my issue. Thanks, though!

Comment: Yeah, a `View` can be drawn many times over unexpectedly. That's why I was trying to get you to move it out of that method. Why didn't you just move it to `onAttachedToWindow()` like I suggested? No need for a `boolean` flag, and the related unnecessary repeated checks. You don't want to do anything in the draw routine that you don't have to.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be an even better solution, thanks! I was googling around for the sequence of a view lifecycle, and this method never came up.

Comment: Ah, yeah, now that I reread my comments, I see that I wasn't very clear about what I was trying to suggest. My apologies. That was at the end of a long day for me. :-) Anyhoo, glad you got things working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initPassedLayout() was getting called many times. Upon logging a few things, I learned dispatchDraw() is called over and over. After overriding and using 'onAttachedToWindow()', my problem has a fix.